# Binaries not removed from file system when the component is unpublished

Tags: content-delivery, publishing, dd4t

I have a multimedia component and it is linked in Content component. When I publish the component, the binary should be stored in the file system without any tcmid. e.g A multimedia component with filename "image1.png" should be stored on the file system as "image1.png".

To implement the above scenario, I did not use DD4T "Publish Binaries for component". I have created a custom publish binaries TBB.

I have mentioned below parameter for AddBinary function.
Binarystream,filename,variant Id(same as filename),component object,multimediaType

```
AddBinary(stream,"image1.png","image1.png",
          multimediaComp,multimediaComponentType).
```

Using this custom TBB, if I publish the component, the binary files are stored in file system. but when i unpublish the component the binaries are not removed from the file system.

What is the reason behind this and how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Welcome to Tridion Stack Exchange, but I would recommend doing some research and pay attention while creating new question as that might give you the answers right away or at least some guideline straight away. Anyway, I hope the below question and view points provided in it might be helpful to you: [http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1556/binary-not-being-removed-from-filesystem/1558#1558](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1556/binary-not-being-removed-from-filesystem/1558#1558)

Answer (score 3):

This is most likely due to other Component Presentations or Pages referencing the same binary file.

The deployer should manage these references, and when there are no more published items pointing at the binary, it will remove them.

This is all covered in this post: [Binary not being removed from filesystem](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1556/binary-not-being-removed-from-filesystem/1558#1558)